# How to get post parent in Wordpress/Woocommerce product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a front end form that allows users to post products to our Woocommerce shop via a form on front end.

I am working with the code below so that each product uploaded is setup as a variable product instead of a simple product.

I am using the Wordpress wp_insert_post to insert these "variations" but I am having trouble getting the post parent id (product ID)

Can anyone offer any help?

Here is what I have so far:

```
global $wc_product_vendors, $woocommerce, $post, $product;
$product_id = $post->ID;
    $i=1;
         while ($i<=3) {

        // Create post object
        $my_post = array(
          'post_title'    => 'Variation #' . $i . ' of ' . wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['post_title'] ),
          'post_name'     => 'product-' . $product_id . '-variation-' . $i,
          'post_status'   => 'publish',
          'post_parent'   => $product_id,
          'post_type'     => 'product_variation',
          'guid'          =>  home_url() . '/?product_variation=product-' . $product_id . '-variation' . $i,
          'post_author'   => $vendor_data->term_id
        );

        // Insert the post into the database
        wp_insert_post( $my_post );
        $i++;
        } //endwhile
```

Currently I am using `$product_id` but it is not giving me the post parent (product) id